# See more function like facebook

Tags: php, facebook

I'd like to limit my words in my website to make it short and then there's a link in see more.  Here is the code:

```
    <?php include('konek.php');

    function excerpts($string, $word_limit = 30)
    {
        $words = explode(" ",$string);

        return implode(" ",array_splice($words,0,$word_limit));
    }
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblannouncement ORDER BY annTime DESC");
    $total_results = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $content=$_POST['annContent'];

    echo excerpts($content,20) . '...<br /><a href="/try.php">Read more</a>';
    ?>
```

but when i click the read more, nothing happens. It did not display the other content of annContent.

Comment: This question is not very clear; do you want the contents to come from a database? If so, what's the problem that prevents you from just doing that?

Comment: <code><?php
include('konek.php');

    function excerpts($string, $word_limit = 30)
    {
        $words = explode(" ",$string);
        
        return implode(" ",array_splice($words,0,$word_limit));
    }
 $content=$_POST['annContent'];
 $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblannouncement ORDER BY annTime DESC");
 $total_results = mysql_num_rows($result);
  
    echo excerpts($content,20) . '...<br /><a href="/read_more.php">Read more</a>';
?></code>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read more on the same page:

```
<?php include('konek.php');

function cutStr($string, $word_limit = 30)
{
    $words = explode(" ",$string);

    return implode(" ",array_splice($words,0,$word_limit));
}
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblannouncement ORDER BY annTime DESC");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
if(isset($_REQUEST['read'])){
echo $row['annContent'];
} else{
echo cutStr($row['annContent'],20) . '...<br /><a href="?read">Read more</a>';
}
}
?>
```

As for reading more on new page, you can send text viam form or call content from Mysql on the new page using a key to identify from main page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the results actually..

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo excerpts($row['annContent'],20) . '...<br /><a href="/try.php">Read more</a>';
}
```

#### The whole code..

```
<?php include('konek.php');

function excerpts($string, $word_limit = 30)
{
    $words = explode(" ",$string);

    return implode(" ",array_splice($words,0,$word_limit));
}
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblannouncement ORDER BY annTime DESC");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo excerpts($row['annContent'],20) . '...<br /><a href="/try.php">Read more</a>';
}
```

Comment: IT worked! thank you! by the way, there's another problem. the href    echo excerpts($row['annContent'],20) . '...<br /><a href="/try.php">Read more</a>';  it says that object not found.

Comment: object not found ?? So how did you say it worked. I dont get it :) .

Comment: it limits the words but when i click read more, it says object not found

Comment: Ahh that one.. the file `try.php` may not be available .. try removing the `/` if it is under the same directory where this php file is.

Comment: after i clicked the read more, the other contents are not displayed.

Comment: Hmmm, That's not how it works.. What do you have inside `try.php`? Can you update your question ?

Comment: I don't see any changes O.o ?

Comment: but when i click the read more, nothing happens. It did not display the other content of annContent.

Comment: [RELATED QUESTION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23193508/functionexcerpt-inside-mysql-result)